# importing shapefiles into AutoCAD map

Tags: shapefile, import, autocad

I need to import a complex polygon shape file into AutoCAD (AutoCAD map 3D 2015).
I can import using Mapimport command, I can use the shp attributes to split into different drawing layers etc.

What I am having problems with is that all the shared boundaries are creating duplicate lines in the drawing. The reason I am importing into CAD is to create topologies and for this there must be a single line between adjacent polygons,, not 2 shared lines on top of each other. Is there any way to prevent the duplicate lines during import or is there a way to get rid of it after import. I imported polygons as closed polylines.

Comment: You can build topology in AutoCAD MAP,  too. Before it you have to use Drawing Cleanup to remove double borderlines.

Comment: I have tried Drawing cleanup, but for some reason it is not deleting the duplicates. Do I need to first break crossing objects?